# Can I reset wordpress without losing posts, comments, media and widgets?

Tags: reset

I a having too many errors on my blog recently. I tried everything (including posting in this forum), but couldn't sort it out. Would it be possible to reset my WordPress website without losing posts, comments, media and widgets?

I have installed a plugin called [WordPress Database Reset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-reset/), but not sure about what options I should pick to keep posts, media, etc.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

> *Would it be possible to reset my WordPress website without losing posts, comments, media and widgets?*

First thing first, please make a backup before make permanent changes...

If you want to keep just your **posts**, **comments**, **media** and **widgets** these tables are ones you do not want to reset:

- `wp_post` and `wp_postmeta` - pages, posts, media, custom posts, etc
- `wp_comments` and `wp_commentmeta` - all comments
- `wp_options` - widgets

Also, if you reset `wp_users` table, make sure you can login...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot above, the plugin you have installed should be able to do it. In order to keep your posts & media and comments you would need to leave out the posts, postmeta and comments options. The one related to postmeta will contain everything to do with who posted it, post id, media included etc, although I would advocate the option I set out next, as it is less likely to mess everything up.

A separate option is install a fresh copy of WordPress, and then export your current blog into your new one. This will mean you can keep everything you need, but you get a fresh database etc to use.

The options are under Tools --> Export to export the blog (you can pick what to export) and Tools --> Import to bring everything into your new WordPress install (This does require a plugin, but it is mentioned on the import page).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. So do I just instal new wordpress under the same domein? it asks me to tick this option: 'I understand that installing on the same domain will overwrite any files' will I just have to delete my old wordpress after all?

Comment: You can install it into another folder to prevent the overwriting of any new files. If you don't wish to do this, once you have backed up the DB just overwrite the install, and it will set WordPress back to fresh but not the DB.

I forgot to mention in my original post, that you mentioned you were having problems, but you did not clarify what these where. Please provide a few extra details just to see if it is definitely a new install you require.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Data is spread around, and the name of the table is not a very good indication of where the data in it is used. Any core table you delete might end up in unusable site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Back up your entire database and files first.
2. Use the export functionality that comes native with WordPress to download all of your posts, media, and widgets.
3. After you've finished exporting everything you want to keep, follow the instructions in [this link](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-uninstall-and-reinstall-wordpress-245) to uninstall and re-install WordPress.
4. Once you're finished, use [WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) to import all those files back into your system.

It's all gravy from there.